# I need two instances of AngularJS $http service or what?

Tags: http, service, error-handling, angularjs, interceptor

I want add a response interceptor to my $http service for error handling purposes. The interceptor logic include send errors messages to server using $http in case necessary, *BUT* I don't want send errors messages to the server about errors messages, I mean, I want disable my interceptor while sending error message to the server.

My idea was create a service named 'remote_log' and put inside it all the code needed to send error to server. That service of course will use the $http service and have it in its dependency list.

Then add as dependency of the interceptor to the 'remote_log' service, and use the 'remote_log' inside the interceptor when need send errors to the server. The problems is that:

Interceptors must be defined using the $httpProvider when the $http service still is not instantiated/accessible, so, inside the interceptor code can't be a dependency to that the  $http service because a "Circular dependency" error happen.

I think my only option is create a separate instance of the $http service inside my 'remote_log', an instance that don't uses the $httpProvider configuration I set while creating the interceptor. My question is: How can I do that? Any other ideas?

Comment: it would be useful if you shared relevant snippets of your code

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## 1. Circular dependency problem.

So, why does the error appear? Here is a quick overview of the process:

1. $http service is requested.
2. $httpProvider is asked to construct it.
3. During construction you register interceptor, that requests $http service not existing yet.
4. You get "Circular dependency" error.

### First solution.

Create your dependency using angular.injector(). Notice, that you will create another $http service, independent from your app.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
    $injector = angular.injector();
    return {
        response: function(response) {
            $injector.invoke(function($http) {
                // This is the exterior $http service!
                // This interceptor will not affect it.
            });
        }
    };
});
```

### Second solution (better).

Inject $injector in your interceptor and use it to retrieve dependencies after $http initialization, right at the time you need them. These dependencies are registered services of your app and will not be created anew!

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $injector) {
    return {
        response: function(response) {
            $injector.invoke(function($http, someService) {
                // $http is already constructed at the time and you may
                // use it, just as any other service registered in your
                // app module and modules on which app depends on.
            });
        }
    };
});
```

## 2. Interception prevention problem.

If you use the second solution, there are actually two problems:

1. If you utilize $http service inside your
   interceptor, you may end up with infinite interceptions: you send
   request, interceptor catches it, sends another, catches another,
   send again, and so on.
2. Sometimes you want just prevent request from being intercepted.

The 'config' parameter of $http service is just an object. You may create a convention, providing custom parameters and recognizing them in your interceptors.

For example, let's add "nointercept" property to config and try duplicate every user request. This is a silly application, but useful example to understand the behavior:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $injector) {
    return {
        response: function(response) {
            if (response.config.nointercept) {
                return $q.when(response); // let it pass
            } else {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                $injector.invoke(function($http) {
                    // This modification prevents interception:
                    response.config.nointercept = true;
                    // Reuse modified config and send the same request again:
                    $http(response.config)
                        .then(function(resp) { defer.resolve(resp); },
                              function(resp) { defer.reject(resp); });
                });
                return defer.promise;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Having the testing for property in interceptor, you may prevent the interception in controllers and services:

```
app.controller('myController', function($http) {
    // The second parameter is actually 'config', see API docs.
    // This query will not be duplicated by the interceptor.
    $http.get('/foo/bar', {nointercept: true})
        .success(function(data) {
            // ...
        });

});
```

Comment: This saved me so much time. Thanks for the good explanation, and taking the time to discuss issues with the approach.

Comment: This should be in the official documentation. The official documentation demonstrates injecting arbitrary dependencies, which served me very, very poorly. Thank you @Thaumant.

Comment: Just to reiterate what people above have said, thanks for going the extra mile and explaining this properly

Comment: I was injecting my services like: angular.module('app.utils').factory('AuthInterceptor',
  ['$q', '$state',
  function($q, $state) { which was working just fine, but after an upgrade of AngularJS it gives me the circular dependency issue on the $state service. It worked before and now it's broken. The solution is interesting but it forces us to inject for each and every request and response type. I wish I could keep my code as is.

Comment: @thaumant I tried to apply first and second solution but I'm getting syntax errors, any help? :(

Comment: @ggderas Fixed the syntax, you can copy-paste it now :)

Answer (score 0):

I used what is described in the answer but I used the syntax with a factory because with the anonymous function it didn't work, I don't really know why:

```
(function(angular){
    angular.module('app', [])
    .config([
        '$httpProvider',
        function($httpProvider) {
                $httpProvider.interceptors.push('Interceptor');
        } 
    ])
    .factory('Interceptor', [
        '$injector',
        InterceptorFactory
    ]);

    function InterceptorFactory($injector){

        return {
            request: function(config) {             
                var ServiceWithHttp = $injector.get('ServiceWithHttp');
                // Use ServiceWithHttp
                return config;
            }
        };
    }

}(window.angular));
```