# AngularJS HTTP Interceptor, Service & AngularStrap's Alert

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I wrote a factory for a NotificationService which will be called in my interceptors to detect for HTTP 4xx status codes and cause an alert to show up on the top of the screen.  The alerts use [AngularStrap's alert module](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##alerts).

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  'app.filters',
  'app.services',
  'mgcrea.ngStrap.alert'
]);

var Svc = angular.module('app.services', []);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
  // Setup all states here…
  $stateProvider
     .state('home')
     .state('about')
     .state('blog');
  // Interceptor
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push("myInterceptor");
});
```

**NotificationService.js**

```
Svc.factory('NotificationService', function($alert) {
  var obj = {};

  // default options for AngularStrap $alert
  var default_options = {
    placement: 'top',
    show: true,
    duration: 3,
    container: 'body'
  }
  obj.error = function(data) {
    angular.extend(default_options, data);  // Merge 'message' property of data into default options
    default_options.type = 'danger';
    $alert(default_options);    // This triggers the alert appearing in the view
  }
  return obj;
});
```

**myInterceptor.js**

```
Svc.factory('myInterceptor', function($q, NotificationService) {
   return {
        responseError: function (response) {
            // Show an alert with the message property in response.data
            NotificationService.error(response.data);

            // do something on error
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
});
```

Something about my code is terribly wrong, but I'm not sure where.  Reading AngularStrap's documentation it mentions that `$alert` is exposed as a service which can be used in a controller/directive.  Does it matter if I use it in another factory?  Is it how I included the `mgcrea.ngStrap.alert` dependency (should it be in the app.services array instead)?

I can't remember the exact error message (it's at work) but the error points to [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24injector/unpr).  What I could remember about the error is that it prints something like this:

```
$modalProvider <- $alert <- NotifcationService <- <blah blah blah>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

their docs say that you need to include modal module as well, probably before the alert module

mgcrea.ngStrap.modal

And yeah, it should definitely be included as dependency in the module where you are actually injecting the $alert service, which is app.services

Comment: No. That is wrong answer. AngularStrap dont even use that in their own examples. `angular.module('myApp')
.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $alert) {
  var myAlert = $alert({title: 'Holy guacamole!', content: 'Best check yo self, you\'re not looking too good.', placement: 'top', type: 'info', show: true});
})` Source: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##alerts

Comment: @SirBenBenji in your link: ```Alerts require the modal plugin to be included.```

Comment: Incidentally, their examples module 'mgcrea.ngStrapDocs' depends on ['mgcrea.ngStrap'](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/docs/scripts/app.js#L4) which in turn depends on ['mgcrea.ngStrap.modal'](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/module.js#L4)

Answer (score 0):

> Inject $injector in your interceptor and use it to retrieve dependencies after $http initialization, right at the time you need them. These dependencies are registered services of your app and will not be created anew!

Source: [I need two instances of AngularJS $http service or what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681654/i-need-two-instances-of-angularjs-http-service-or-what)