# Using a service within a service Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to inject a bootstrap-ui $modal service into my factory, but when I do I get a circular dependency issue and when I don't $modal is not defined. The code looks like:

```
retryModule = angular.module('g4plus.retry-call', ['ui.bootstrap'])

retryModule.factory 'RetryCall', ($q, $rootScope)->
  requests = {}
  failedRequests = {}
  uniqueId = 0
  modalInstance = undefined
  modalClose = true

### Some more code

    alertUser = ()->
    modalInstance = $modal.open
      template: """
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          ... Some more code ...
```

How can I use $modal within my factory? Please don't ask me to put this code in a directive, because that defeats the purpose. If I could have put this in a directive I would have had this project done already. The same goes for controllers.

Thanks!

If I inject $modal into my factory the circular dependency error is:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $modal <- RetryCall <- $http <- $compile

Comment: What is the circular dependency error are you getting?  Can you provide runnable code?  Why does using a directive or controller defeat the purpose?  ( which purpose does it defeat? )

Comment: I'm making a global http interceptor that will display a modal when there is an error to connect. This shouldn't be dependent on adding a directive to the html, but instead allow the developer to simply include the factory and call it a day. The error is:Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $modal <- RetryCall <- $http <- $compile

Comment: sounds like a module to me. developers will be able to set their app to depend on that module, and perhaps declare a directive in it and call it a day. it's not too much work, and that's what directives are for.

Comment: The code does sit inside a module that is imported. I'm just trying to use a simple service with in my code. Forget that the $modal service does any DOM stuff, all that I need to know is how to use that service.

Comment: I do not see anything in the code you posted that requires `$modal`... I think the circular dependency is because `$modal` requires `$http` and you are trying to set up an interceptor.  Can you please post more code?  How are you setting up your `$http` interceptor?  What is the full definition of `RetryCall` and where are you requiring `$modal`?

Comment: @rtcherry: Thanks, $http in $modal explains the circular dependency. Now that I think about it, it makes total sense. This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original comment:** I do not see anything in the code you posted that requires `$modal`... I think the circular dependency is because `$modal` requires `$http` and you are trying to set up an interceptor. Can you please post more code? How are you setting up your `$http` interceptor? What is the full definition of `RetryCall` and where are you requiring `$modal`?

**Possible Answer:** Create your interceptor as a normal AngularJS service (call it something like `yourHttpInterceptor`, and then add it by using

```
yourAngularModule.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('yourHttpInterceptor');
}]);
```

Alternatively, you can create an anonymous factory

```
yourAngularModule.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$modal', function($modal) {
        return {
            request: function(config) {
                 // Do something...
            },
            ...
        }
    }]));
}]);
```

Comment: I already do that. Sorry if I didn't post the code in it's entirety but I felt that I showed the relevant parts.

Comment: No this not solution.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer doesn't provide a working solution.

The problem here is that `$modal` depends on `$http`. `$modal` cannot ask for `$http` in the interceptor because `$http` does not yet exist (since you are still in the config phase, configuring the `$httpProvider`).

This answer by user thaumant explains how to work around this, here:

[I need two instances of AngularJS $http service or what?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19954545/2943490)