# AngularJS circular dependency issue with $http

Tags: angularjs

I am having an issue with circular dependancy. I built a `$http` interceptor to handle all `$http` errors and alert the user with a modal(Angular UI-Bootstrap).

**The dependency chain looks like this:**

`$http <- $modal <- ErrorHandlerService <- HTTPErrorInterceptorService <- $http`

**The error I am getting is:**

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- $modal <- ErrorHandlerService <- HTTPErrorInterceptorService <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state`

I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647483/angularjs-injecting-service-into-a-http-interceptor-circular-dependency)  that the trick to getting around these types of issues is to use `$injector`. I have tried using `$injector` to inject `$modal`, I have tried using `$injector` to inject `ErrorHandlerService` but I am still getting the `Circular dependency error`.

Does anybody have any ideas how to get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that anything that depends on `$http` service cannot be injected into a `$http` interceptor. I haven't find any way to workaround this, just avoid using `$http`-dependant stuff in interceptors

Comment: I wonder if you could do an $emit or $broadcast in the interceptor, just a thought.

Comment: Have you tried this approach:http://stackoverflow.com/a/19954545/2407203 ?

Answer (score 8):

The important point of the [trick](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2367) in the [mentioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647483/angularjs-injecting-service-into-a-http-interceptor-circular-dependency) is, that you resolve the dependency to `$modal` during the runtime of the interceptor, not in the factory.

**This will work**

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('httpAuthInterceptor', function($q, $injector) {
    let $modal;  
    return {
      responseError: (rejection) => {
        if (rejection.status === 401) {
          $modal = $modal || $injector.get('$modal');
          $modal.open({
            template: 'not logged in'
          });
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
    };
  })
;
```

**This will NOT work**

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('httpAuthInterceptor', function($q, $injector) {
    let $modal = $injector.get('$modal');  
    return {
      responseError: (rejection) => {
        ...
      }
    };
  })
 ;
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me, I still get cd error (I have my own service in my interceptor, which itself depends on $http)

Comment: Works for me. @freshfelicio Loading your own service via $injector at run-time should solve the issue, since you clearly have CD due to the HTTP interceptor depending on $http.