# How to use two separate $http service instances in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

I am implementing an angularjs service, which saves the data sent by an `$http` call in `localStorage`. In order to do that, I am using the request interceptor, so that whenever an http request is sent via `$http`, the data is saved in `localStorage`. Below is my code for the interceptor,

```
var OfflinkJs = angular.module('OfflinkJs', []);

OfflinkJs.factory('cacheInterceptor', function () {
    var cacheInterceptor = {
        request: function (config) {
            // Here I am saving the config as a string in localstorage
            return config;
        }
    };
    return cacheInterceptor;
});
```

For above interceptor to work, I have to register it in the `interceptors` array of `$httpProvider`. I have done this to achieve that,

```
OfflinkJs.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('cacheInterceptor');
}]);
```

**PROBLEM**

Now, when I use `OfflinkJS` module in another module, all the `$http` calls go through my interceptor. But I would like to make some requests sent by `$http` service use my interceptor while some other requests **NOT**.

Since `$http` service is a singleton, I cannot figure out how to use two instances of it in separate places of my application. Is there any way to achieve this?

I went through this question, but seems it really addresses the issue of **Circular dependency**

> [I need two instances of AngularJS $http service or what?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14681654/5148311)

Answer (score 0):

I check the URL in the interceptor and use that to filter out requests to other services. I set the base url for my service as a constant in my module, and then check against that.  If the request isn't to the relevant service, it just passes through with no action.

But perhaps a better way would be to set up a data service instead of an interceptor. There are plenty of tutorials out there on data services.